# How to get PyCharm to display unicode data in its console?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, ide, pycharm

I have switched over to PyCharm and have had a blast using it. I code for projects that use languages other than English (i.e. Hebrew and Arabic) and need to debug encodings once in a while. For some reason, PyCharm will not display Unicode characters in its debug console.

I have set the IDE encoding to UTF-8 but it did not help.

Any ideas?

Comment: You say it will not display Unicode characters. What does it display instead? An error message? Mojibake?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The accepted answer is no longer correct.  Of the default fonts, none of them make a difference.  I just spent awhile going through this same problem and the best solution is to modify your .bash_profile (or .zshrc) and include the line:

```
export PYTHONIOENCODING=UTF-8
```

In theory, you could also add this to your Environment Variables which you can set from within Preferences->Build,Execution,Deployment->Python Console
This approach, however, seems to be broken in the build I am using (4.0.4)

Comment: Best solution is to add that line to the startup script of PyCharm.

Answer (score 11):

You need to change the **console font** to the one which contains the required Unicode glyphs:

[image: console font]

Comment: Thank you...that is exactly what helped. Great screen shot

Comment: I'm having the same problem, unicodes display '?' with white background. which even breaks bpython, it's kind of annoying. This solution hasn't helped me (no Consolas font, but all the ones I tried gave same result... using PyCharm 3.4.1), any other clue ?