# How to fix the ugly appearance of Unicode symbols in Pycharm 4.5 debugger?

Tags: debugging, unicode, pycharm

May be you know how to fix this ugly appearance of cyrillic chars in Pycharm's debugger?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLPAh.png]

[How to get PyCharm to display unicode data in its console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188655/how-to-get-pycharm-to-display-unicode-data-in-its-console) - I tried it, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that there is no way to view bytes as encoded Unicode strings in debugger.

But there is a different approach:
1) create duplicate object
2) process dictionary's entries for encoding in utf-8