# How to display runes in pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, character

I want to write this in pycharm

```
elder = 'ᚠᚢᚦᚨᚱᚲᚷᚹᚺᚾᛁᛃᛈᛇᛉᛊᛏᛒᛖᛗᛚᛜᛞᛟ'
```

But it displays only empty squares

```
elder = '□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□□'
```

Comment: The font you selected for the editor has no definitions for those characters. They will still show fine if you output them with an appropriate font.

Answer (score 0):

you're using some special characters (Unicode), and Pycharm doesn't support [all charactersets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters) out there out-of-the-box. yet, you can configure it to do so if you like as instructed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14188655/8956917). but keep in mind it always depends on the environment configuration whether a unicode character is defined and displayed correctly or as question marks or empty boxes. so your program might still show them in other systems and consoles.